# Is this a way light/information could escape from a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, photons, spacetime, information

Since we have now confirmed that two black holes can combine into one, I have wondered about the Lagrange point (balancing of gravity) that has to exist between them.  As the two holes approach and get very close, would the Lagrange point temporarily become a place where there is no event horizon?  For a moment, would it be a place where trapped photons and information could escape from the black holes?

Comment: I would guess that the Lagrange points (a classical Newtonian concept btw) are always outside the EH of either black hole (though I've not done the calculation) so anything that did emerge would not violate the BH definition. BTW a great deal of gravitational radiation does escape from the event but this also does not violate the definition.